# xml, get calendar-data (davical calendar)

Tags: php, xml, caldav

I want to get `calendar-data` from XML.

XML source:

```
 <response>
  <href>/caldav.php/admin/test/test.ics</href>
  <propstat>
   <prop>
    <getcontenttype>text/calendar</getcontenttype>
    <getetag>"674fb05966bc1eb50aa86a2c4ca40b4a"</getetag>
    <C:calendar-data>BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
CREATED:20180510T122608Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20180511T130531Z
DTSTAMP:20180511T130531Z
UID:x7cnad21-40gt-ck6l-hseq-xfwwoinkr1tw
SUMMARY:Pazar Günü Test 2
TRANSP:OPAQUE
DESCRIPTION:Açıklama 2
CLASS:PUBLIC
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20180524
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20180525
END:VEVENT
PRODID:-//Inf-IT//CalDavZAP 0.13.1//EN
END:VCALENDAR
</C:calendar-data>
   </prop>
   <status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</status>
  </propstat>
 </response>
```

I can get a tag like this:

```
 echo $item->propstat->prop->getatag;
```

But I can't get `calendar-data`.

Comment: Hi @homeland, what happens when you try to get `calendar-data`, what text is outputted, and what other things have you tried?

Comment: Output is empty.  I tried  prop->{'C:calendar-data'}

Answer (score 0):

The namespace prefix will most likely cause the access problem as it would create an illegal property. You may try to create an array instead using:

```
$xmlFromCalendar = ... // add your code to retrieve the XML data
$arrConverted= (array)simplexml_load_string($xmlFromCalendar);
```

After conversion, you should be able to access the element with array syntax:

```
print $arrConverted['propstat']['prop']['C:calendar-data'];
```

Before, try to do a `var_dump($item);` and observe the structure of the generated XML file and if you can find the element in it. Depending on the XML parser namespace prefixes may automatically be removed/escaped so it may be that your element can be found under a different name.